# Java iText Delete and update

Tags: java, itext

I was searching an example of how to edit and remove one annotation form a PDF file using iText; but I found anyone.

Is possible to do that? if yes could you explain me how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Removing is pretty easy but would you care to explain which aspects of an annotation you wish to edit? Do you want to change its position? Its appearance? Its contents? Which kinds of annotations do you have on your mind?

Comment: Common Annotation, and I want to change basically their content and their position

Answer (score 0):

Use PdfStamper (below is the example groovy code)

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader( baos.toByteArray() )
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper( reader, out, reader.pdfVersion )
stamp.setEncryption null, null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_40

stamp.acroFields.removeField( 'field to remove' )

try{
  BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont( BaseFont.HELVETICA,  BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED )
  ( 1..reader.numberOfPages ).each{
    PdfContentByte over = stamp.getOverContent( it )
    over.beginText()
    over.setFontAndSize bf, 5
    over.showTextAligned PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "your annotation", 0, 0, 0f
    over.endText()
  }
}finally{
  stamp.close()
  baos.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment, the OP is interested in

> Common Annotation, and I want to change basically their content and their position.

You can move annotations like this:

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resourceStream);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("target/test-outputs/test-annotated-moved.pdf"));

        PdfDictionary page1 = reader.getPageNRelease(1);
        PdfArray annots = page1.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < annots.size(); i++)
        {
            PdfDictionary annot = annots.getAsDict(i);
            PdfArray rect = annot.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
            PdfArray movedRect = new PdfArray(new float[] {
                    rect.getAsNumber(0).floatValue() + 100f,
                    rect.getAsNumber(1).floatValue() + 100f,
                    rect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue() + 100f,
                    rect.getAsNumber(3).floatValue() + 100f
                    }
            );
            annot.put(PdfName.RECT, movedRect);
            stamper.markUsed(annot);
        }

        stamper.close();
```

(This example moves all annotations on the first page right and up by 100 default user space units.)

You can edit annotations based on the **Contents** value like this:

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resourceStream);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("target/test-outputs/test-annotated-edited.pdf"));

        PdfDictionary page1 = reader.getPageNRelease(1);
        PdfArray annots = page1.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < annots.size(); i++)
        {
            PdfDictionary annot = annots.getAsDict(i);
            PdfString contents = annot.getAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
            if (contents != null)
            {
                String value = contents.toString();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(value);
                value = builder.reverse().toString();
                annot.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(value));
                annot.remove(PdfName.AP);
            }
            stamper.markUsed(annot);
        }

        stamper.close();
```

(This example inverts the character sequence of all annotations with **Contents**; to make sure that the **Contents** is used, the existing appearances **AP** are removed. Any serious application will of course try to be more specific here...)