# getImportedPage without annotation

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to use PdfStamper to enlarge every page, and copy some pages.

Enlarge every page:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            page = reader.getPageN(i);
            media = page.getAsArray(PdfName.CROPBOX);
            if (media == null) {
                media = page.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
            }
            crop = new PdfArray();
            crop.add(new PdfNumber(0));
            crop.add(new PdfNumber(0));
            float w = media.getAsNumber(2).floatValue();
            crop.add(new PdfNumber(media.getAsNumber(2).floatValue() * 2));
            crop.add(new PdfNumber(media.getAsNumber(3).floatValue() * 1));
            page.put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, crop);
            page.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, crop);

            stamper.getUnderContent(i).setLiteral(String.format("\nq 1 0 0 1 %.1f 0 cm\nq\n", w / 2));
            stamper.getOverContent(i).setLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
        }
```

Insert an empty page, and copy content from page 1.

```
stamper.insertPage(2, stamper.getReader().getPageSize(1))
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(2);
PdfImportedPage ip = stamper.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
Image ipage = Image.getInstance(ip);
canvas.addImage(ipage);
```

But I found PdfImportedPage deletes annotations, and after I enlarge a page the annotations are in the wrong position.

How can I handle these annotations, both when copying a page and when enlarging.

[image: Source PDF page]

[image: Enlarged PDF page]

[image: Copy from page 1]

Answer (score 1):

### Displaced Annotations

> after I enlarge a page the annotations are in the wrong position.

#### The Cause Of Their Displacement

The cause for this is simple: You (attempt to) enlarge the page to the right and then you prepend a shift to the right for the static page content. But you don't move the annotations. Thus, the annotations remain in their original position while the static page content is moved away.

#### What Needs To Be Done

If you actually want to move the coordinates of the static content, you also have to move all the other coordinate arguments in the PDF which relate to that content. This means in particular annotations (multiple entries), destinations, and structure tree information.

A complete implementation thereof is beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer.

#### A Simpler Option

You (attempt to) enlarge the page to the right and then you prepend a shift to the right for the static page content. Why don't you simply **enlarge the page half as far both to the left and the right** and leave the content at its coordinates? Then you do not need to change any coordinates at all...

### Vanished Annotations

> PdfImportedPage deletes annotations

#### The Cause Of Their Vanishment

The `getImportedPage` implementations of both the basic `PdfWriter` and the `PdfStamper` merely copy the static page content, not the annotations or other extra s. The reason is that in these cases the page is imported as a form Xobject which can be drawn in the content of any content stream (of a page, of an annotation, of another Xobject, ...) but which simply cannot have annotations of its own.

#### What Can Be Done

You can either flatten all annotations in a preparation step (using a `PdfStamper` and calling `setAnnotationFlattening` and `setFormFlattening`) or duplicate the page  in a preparation step (using `PdfCopy` and its `getImportedPage`).

The former option is keeping document level information but makes the dynamic annotation contents static. The latter option looses document level information but keeps annotations dynamic.

Comment: I move the annotations for solve Displaced Annotations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056928/java-itext-delete-and-update

Comment: Ok. But please be aware that my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21262742/1729265) to that question is a bit naive - I only considered the **Rect** position and dimension of the annotations, but for some annotation types there are additional, more fine-grained coordinates which are not corrected by that code. And other entities with coordinates are not adjusted at all.

Comment: Ok, Ok.
More question, about duplicate the page with annotations, I try the former option.
But when I setAnnotationFlattening(true) and setFormFlattening(true), all annotations are disappear, include the base page.

```
        PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(2);
        stamper.setAnnotationFlattening(true);
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        PdfImportedPage ip = stamper.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
        Image ipage = Image.getInstance(ip);
        ipage.setAbsolutePosition(ip.getWidth() / 4, 0);
        canvas.addImage(ipage)
```

Comment: *"But when I setAnnotationFlattening(true) and setFormFlattening(true), all annotations are disappear"* - that sounds like iText 5 cannot properly create annotation appearances if they are not provided by the PDF.